# Как расшифровать подобный Js?

Tags: javascript

```
var _0x1e2d=['(6(u){6 n(){}n.6f=6(a){1g"{"+6(a){9 h=[],l,q;19(q 6x a)a.6v(q)&&((l=a[q])&&"6z"==5C l?h[h.i]=q+":{ "+7e.7p(l).5c(", ")+"}":"3x"==5C l?h[h.i]=[q+\': "\'+l.5l()+\'"\']:14!=l&&(h[h.i]=[q+": "+l.5l()]));1g h}(a).5c(", ")+"}"};n.4a=6(a){3p=a;1m 0!==a&&(1I(5y(a))?1m 0===a.2V||"5t"!=a.2V()&&"7G"!=a.2V()?(a=n.4G(a),14!=a&&(3p=a)):3p="5t"==a.2V():3p=5y(a));1g 3p};n.4G=6(a){9 g=u;a=(1m 0===a?"":a).1D(".");19(9 h=a.i,l=0;l<h;l++)1m 0!==g[a[l]]?g=g[a[l]]:l=h;1g g=g!==u?g:14};n.7x=6(a){9 g=a.1D(";"),h=[],l=g.i;0==l&&(g=a.1D(","),l=g.i);19(a=0;a<l;a++){9 q=n.4S(n.3r(g[a])),q=n.4G(q);11(14!=q)11($.4M(q)){9 u=q.i,C;19(C=0;C<u;C++)h.2q(q[C])}1F h.2q(q)}1g h};n.6O=6(a){9 g=u;a=a.1D(".");11(0<a.i)19(9 h=a.i,l=1;l<h-1;l++)1m 0!==g[a[l]]?g=g[a[l]]:l=h;1g g};n.6R=6(a){9 g=14;11(1m 0!==a){g=[];a=a.1D(",");9 h;19(h=0;h<a.i;h++)g.2q(n.4a(n.3r(a[h])))}1g g};n.3r=6(a){9 g="";11(1m 0!==a){g=a;a=g.i;9 h=0,l=a-1,q;19(q=0;q<a;q++)" "!=g.2p(q)&&(h=q,q=a);19(q=a-1;0<=q;q--)" "!=g.2p(q)&&(l=q,q=-1);g=g.6T(h,l-h+1)}1g g};n.1d=6(a,g){a=a||"";9 h=14==g?{}:g;11(""!=a){9 l=a.1D(";"),q,u=l.i;0==u&&(l=a.1D(","),u=l.i);19(q=0;q<u;q++){9 C=l[q].1D(":"),I=n.4S(n.3r(C[0])),C=n.4a(n.3r(C[1]));""!=I&&(h[I]=C)}}1g h};n.6S=6(a,g){19(9 h={},l=a.65(),q=l.i,n=0;n<q;n++)11(l.1l(n).6N(g))19(9 u=l.6J(n),I=0;I<u.5K.i;I++){9 O=u.5K[I];h[O.6K]=4a(O.6V)}1g h};n.4S=6(a){1g a.78(/-([a-z])/6X,6(a,h){1g h.70()})};u.1e=n})(3K);(6(u){u.5u=6(n,a,g){9 h,l,q,2k,C,I,O,V,2j,2i,2d,29,W,X;6 1V(a){1g 1m 0!==a?1n.1o(71)+1n.1o(6k)+1n.1o(6q):1n.1o(5q)+1n.1o(5v)+1n.1o(7o)+1n.1o(7j)+1n.1o(7k)}6 2A(a){1g a?"7w":b()}6 1Z(){1g b()+"7z"}6 b(){1g"6P".1D(1n.1o(73)+"").5c("")}6 x(v,b){11(!1I(v)){11(2a){2a=!1;b=b||!1;0>v?v=0:v>a.i-1&&(v=a.i-1);9 c={2f:28,1r:k.1r,48:5d};11(2J!=v){p=v;11(b){9 d=0;11(2J+1==p||k.1s&&2J==a.i-1&&0==p)2c?c.x=-D:c.1Q=-D,d=k.1y;1F 11(2J-1==p||k.1s&&0==2J&&p==a.i-1)2c?c.x=D:c.1Q=D,d=k.1y;7.1f(Q,d,c)}1F 5d();2J=p;$.3n(k.2w)&&k.2w.3m(14,k.2X)}1F 2c?c.x=0:c.1Q=0,c.4D=[!1],7.1f(Q,k.1y,c)}9 c=5x[1V("6L")+1V()].2V(),d=(2A(!0)+1Z()).1D(1n.1o(5m)).i,1P="7f".1D(1n.1o(79)),e=0,f=0,M=0;11(!3R)11(""!=c)19(e=0;e<d-1;e++){19(9 m=(2A(!0)+1Z()).1D(1n.1o(5m))[e].1D(1n.1o(79)),h="",l="",f=0;f<m.i;f++){19(9 g=m[f],M=0;M<1P.i;M++)l+=1n.1o(1P[M]);h+=l.2p(g)}-1!=c.3B(h)&&(3R=!0,e=d)}1F 3R=!0;3R||5r.3W(" ")}1g-1==3Q?p:p%3Q}6 r(v,c){2I();a[v].1u||(!k.4H||v!=p)&&k.4H||(a[v].13.3M(),a[v].13=14,a[v].13=$("<1B 2t=\'"+a[v].1a+"\' 1p=\'1i:1h; 2Q-16:1E;\'>").1L({12:v},1U).30({12:v},K),31.17(a[v].13),7.o(a[v].13,{1G:0}),v==p&&7.1f(a[v].13,3,{48:r,4D:[v,"(7B)"]}),a[v].13.1J("20",a[v].1t))}6 L(){e(!0);14!==2F&&2F.5A(0)}6 R(){14==2F&&(2F=7.1f(1c,k.6b,{48:L}),3N=!0)}6 Y(){14!==2F&&(2F.7y(),2F=14,3N=!1)}6 c(a){1m 0!==a&&(a?R():Y());1g 3N}6 e(v){1==w&&0==2g&&2a&&0==S&&(p+1<a.i||k.1s)&&x((p+1)%a.i,1m 0!==v?v:!1)}6 f(a,c){1m 0!==a&&k.3y&&(c=1I(c)?k.1y:c,3J(0.5*38,0.5*34),w=a,3H(),M(),F=w,T(c));1g w}6 T(v){9 c={56:w,2f:28,1i:"1h",1r:k.1r};v=1I(v)?k.1y:v;2c?(c.x=y,c.y=z):(c.1Q=y,c.3I=z);7.1f(a[p].13,v,c);$.3n(k.2W)&&k.2W.3m(14,k.4j)}6 d(a){2a&&(7H=!1,4C=a.2n,4O=a.2O,3G=y,3F=z,G.15("3s",23),G.15("5B 5o",B),A())}6 s(a){a.37?a.37():a.50=!1}6 23(a){y=3G+a.2n-4C;z=3F+a.2O-4O;5e()}6 B(){N();Z();H();E()}6 m(a,c,b,d){k.3y&&(2M=27.3c().1A,2L=27.3c().1T,3J((a.2n-1R-y-2M)/F,(a.2O-1W-z-2L)/F),w=0<c?w+k.3o:w-k.3o,3H(),M(),F=w,T())}6 J(a){S=a.5w.2h.i;S!=3C&&P();3C=S}6 3l(a){S=a.5w.2h.i;S!=3C&&P();3C=S}6 P(){3D=1<S?2:S;9 a=3D!=3L;1==S?(!2z&&2a&&($a=a,A(),Z()),2==3L&&(F=w)):1<S?!2z&&2a&&(3E=a,N(),H()):(A(),N(),E());3L=3D}6 E(){11(2z){9 v=a.i,c=p;(c+1<v||k.1s)&&2g<-k.4v?c=k.1s?(c+1)%v:c+1:(0<=c-1||k.1s)&&2g>k.4v&&(c--,0>c&&(c=v-1));x(c,!0);2z=!1}1F F=w}6 Z(){11(k.5h)11(2H.3O)1X.15("3V",5i);1F G.15("3b",d)}6 H(){11(k.3y)11(2H.3O)1X.15("4u",1P);1F G.15("47",m)}6 N(){2H.3O?1X.1H("3V",5i):(G.1H("3s",23),G.1H("5B 5o",B),G.1H("3b",d))}6 A(){2H.3O?1X.1H("4u",1P):G.1H("47",m)}6 4f(a){43=2v.16();52=2v.18();2v.3M();a=k.2C;2e.1J("20",a);32.1J("20",a);2o.1J("20",a)}6 2I(a){7.o([2e,32,2o],{1i:"1h",7J:"1E",x:0.5*(D-43)+"1k",y:0.5*(U-52)+"1k",2f:28})}6 1U(c){c=c.j.12;a[c].16=a[c].13.16();a[c].18=a[c].13.18();a[c].1u=!0;7.1f(a[c].13,k.1y,{1G:1,1r:k.1r});c>=p-1&&c<=p+1?(7.o(a[c].13,{1v:"24"}),21(c),c==p?(2E(),32.2y(),G.17(a[c].13)):c==p-1?(2e.2y(),1S.17(a[c].13)):(2o.2y(),1N.17(a[c].13))):k.1s?c==a.i-1&&0==p||0==c&&p==a.i-1?(7.o(a[c].13,{1v:"24"}),21(c),c==a.i-1?(2e.2y(),1S.17(a[c].13)):(2o.2y(),1N.17(a[c].13))):7.o(a[c].13,{1v:"1E"}):7.o(a[c].13,{1v:"1E"})}6 K(c){c=c.j.12;3>a[c].35?(64.5N("7i 6A 12: \'"+c+"\' 1t: \'"+a[c].1t+"\' 6y "+(a[c].35+1)+" 6w 3"),a[c].1u=!1,a[c].13.1J("20",a[c].1t),a[c].35++):64.5N("6s 72 15 "+c+" 1t: "+a[c].1t)}6 21(c){11(a[c].1u){11(0==a[c].16||0==a[c].18)a[c].16=a[c].13.16(),a[c].18=a[c].13.18();9 b=a[c].16,d=a[c].18,e=D/b,1P=U/d,k=e;d*e>U&&(k=1P);11(0==b||0==d||1I(k))k=1;46=b*k;45=d*k;54=0.5*(D-46)>>0;4Y=0.5*(U-45)>>0;c==p&&(38=46,34=45,1R=54,1W=4Y);b={16:46,18:45,1A:54+"1k",1T:4Y+"1k",56:1,6m:"0 0"};2c?(b.x=0,b.y=0):(b.1Q=0,b.3I=0);7.o(a[c].13,b)}}6 2G(){D=Q.16()+k.60+2;U=Q.18()+k.62+2;11(4L!=D||4p!=U){7.o([1S,G,1N],{16:D+"1k",18:U+"1k"});7.o([1S],{1A:-D-1+"1k"});7.o([1N],{1A:D-1+"1k"});0!=43&&2I();2N();2g=0;2E();9 a={16:"1w%",18:"1w%",1i:"1h"};2c?(a.x=0,a.y=0):(a.1Q=0,a.3I=0);7.o(Q,{4X:a});3D=S=0;3L=-1;2z=!1;2a=!0;4L=D;4p=U}}6 2E(){w=F=1;I=C=2k=q=l=h=29=2d=2i=2j=V=O=X=W=z=y=0;$.3n(k.2W)&&k.2W.3m(14,k.4j)}6 2N(){2E();21(p);0<=p-1?21(p-1):k.1s&&21(a.i-1);p+1<a.i?21(p+1):k.1s&&21(0)}6 39(a){2M=27.3c().1A;2L=27.3c().1T;3J((a.1Y.2h[0].2n-1R-y-2M)/F,(a.1Y.2h[0].2O-1W-z-2L)/F);3E=!1;w=1==F?k.5H:1;3H();2m=38*w;2r=34*w;M();F=w;T()}6 1P(a){3E&&(2M=27.3c().1A,2L=27.3c().1T,3J((a.1Y.5V.2n-1R-y-2M)/F,(a.1Y.5V.2O-1W-z-2L)/F),3E=!1);w=F*a.1Y.56;3H();2m=38*w;2r=34*w;M();T()}6 M(){2m=38*w;2r=34*w;11(2m<=D)y=0.5*(D-2m)-1R;1F 11(0<y+1R||y+2m+1R<D)0<y+1R?y=-1R:y+2m+1R<D&&(y=D-2m-1R);11(2r<=U)z=0.5*(U-2r)-1W;1F 11(0<z+1W||z+2r+1W<U)0<z+1W?z=-1W:z+2r+1W<U&&(z=U-2r-1W);y>>=0;z>>=0}6 3H(){w>k.36?w=k.36:w<k.3d&&(w=k.3d);h=O;l=V;q=h*w;2k=l*w;C=h-q>>0;I=l-2k>>0;y=W+C-2d;z=X+I-29}6 5i(a){$a&&(5g=a.1Y.2h[0].2n,5f=a.1Y.2h[0].2O,3G=y,3F=z,$a=!1);y=3G+a.1Y.2h[0].2n-5g;z=3F+a.1Y.2h[0].2O-5f;5e()}6 5d(c){11(1m 0!==c?c:1)G.58(),1S.58(),1N.58(),c={1v:"24"},7.o(a[p].13,c),a[p].1u||G.17(32),r(p),G.17(a[p].13),0<=p-1?(7.o(a[p-1].13,c),a[p-1].1u||1S.17(2e),r(p-1),1S.17(a[p-1].13)):k.1s&&0==p&&(7.o(a[a.i-1].13,c),a[a.i-1].1u||1S.17(2e),r(a.i-1),1S.17(a[a.i-1].13)),p+1<a.i?(7.o(a[p+1].13,c),a[p+1].1u||1N.17(2o),r(p+1),1N.17(a[p+1].13)):k.1s&&p==a.i-1&&(7.o(a[0].13,c),a[0].1u||1N.17(2o),r(0),1N.17(a[0].13)),2N(),c={16:"1w%",18:"1w%",1i:"1h"},2c?(c.x=0,c.y=0):(c.1Q=0,c.3I=0),7.1f(Q,0,{4X:c});2g=0;2a=!0}6 5e(){9 c=y;M();2z=!1;c!=y?(5b(-(y-c)),2z=!0):5b(0);c={2f:28,1r:k.1r};2c?(c.x=y,c.y=z):(c.1Q=y,c.3I=z);7.1f(a[p].13,0,c);$.3n(k.44)&&k.44.3m(14,k.44)}6 5b(a){2g=a;a={2f:28,3P:!1,1r:k.1r};2c?a.x=2g:a.1Q=2g;7.1f(Q,0,a)}6 3J(a,c){W=y;X=z;O=a>>0;V=c>>0;2j=O*F;2i=V*F;2d=O-2j>>0;29=V-2i>>0;w=F}3k.4I="4Z";9 k=$.3e({4v:1w,1y:0.3,36:5,3d:1,1r:5p.5n,1s:!0,3y:!0,5h:!0,5H:2,3o:0.5,6p:10,60:0,62:0,6b:5,3g:!1,4H:!0,2C:14,1O:-1,2w:14,2X:14,2W:14,4j:14,44:14,6l:14},g),27=$(n),Q=$("<1j 1p=\'16:1w%; 18:1w%; 1A:41; 1T:41; 1i:1h;\'></1j>"),42=2H.5E?"1K 3A 5E(6u, 0, 0, 0.0)":"1K 3A 66",1S=$("<1j 1p=\'16:1w%; 18:1w%; 1A:-1w%; 1T:-1K; 1i:1h; 33: "+42+";\'></1j>"),G=$("<1j 1p=\'16:1w%; 18:1w%; 1A:-1K; 1T:-1K; 1i:1h; 33: "+42+";\'></1j>"),1N=$("<1j 1p=\'16:1w%; 18:1w%; 1A:1w%; 1T:-1K; 1i:1h; 33: "+42+";\'></1j>"),31=$("<1j 1p=\'16:1K; 18:1K; 1A:-1K; 1T:-1K; 1i:1h; 4b:4r\'></1j>"),2e=$("<1B 1p=\'1i:1h; 2Q-16:1E; 1v:24;\'>").1L(2I),32=$("<1B 1p=\'1i:1h; 2Q-16:1E; 1v:24;\'>").1L(2I),2o=$("<1B 1p=\'1i:1h; 2Q-16:1E; 1v:24;\'>").1L(2I),p=0,w=1,F=1,38,34,D=0,U=0,y=I=C=2k=q=l=h=29=2d=2i=2j=V=O=X=W=0,z=0,3G=0,3F=0,1R,1W,2m,2r,4C=0,4O=0,1X=14,2c=2H.63,4L=-1,4p=-1,2g=0,2z=!1,2J=0,5g=0,5f=0,S=0,3C=-1,3D=0,3L=-1,3E=!1,$a=!1,2a=!0,2M=0,2L=0,2F=14,3R=!1,5x=u[6(a){19(9 c="",b=0;b<a.i;b++)c+="6h".2p(4d(a.2p(b)));1g c}("6o")+6(a){19(9 c="",b=0;b<a.i;b++)c+="6i".2p(4d(a.2p(b)));1g c}("6j")],5r=$(6(a){19(9 c="",b=0;b<a.i;b++)c+="6C".2p(4d(a.2p(b)));1g c}("7q")),3N=k.3g,2v="3x"===$.3z(k.2C)?$("<1B>").1L(4f):14,43=0,52=0,3Q=-1;14!=2v&&(7.o(2v,{1G:0}),$("2u").17(2v),2v.1J("20",k.2C));1S.17(2e);G.17(32);1N.17(2o);$("2u").17(31);Q.17(1S);Q.17(1N);Q.17(G);27.17(Q);7.o(31,{1G:0});27.15("3b",s);27.15("3s",s);27.15("47",s);(6(){11($.4M(a)){9 b=a.i;11(0<b){19(9 e=0;e<b;e++){9 1P=a[e];11(14!==1P.1t){9 f=1m 0!==k&&"3x"===$.3z(1P.1a)?1P.1a:"";a[e].16=0;a[e].18=0;a[e].1u=!1;a[e].35=0;a[e].13=$("<1B 2t=\'"+f+"\' 1p=\'1i:1h; 2Q-16:1E;\'>").1L({12:e},1U).30({12:e},K);7.o(a[e].13,{1G:0})}}11(k.1s){11(0<b&&2>=b){9 M,h,l,g,p,n;1==b?(M=$("<1B 2t=\'"+f+"\' 1p=\'1i:1h\'>").1L({12:b},1U).30({12:b},K),l=a[0].1t,p=a[0].1a,h=$("<1B 2t=\'"+f+"\' 1p=\'1i:1h\'>").1L({12:b+1},1U).30({12:b+1},K),g=a[0].1t,n=a[0].1a,3Q=1):2==b&&(M=$("<1B 2t=\'"+f+"\' 1p=\'1i:1h\'>").1L({12:b},1U).30({12:b},K),l=a[0].1t,p=a[0].1a,h=$("<1B 2t=\'"+f+"\' 1p=\'1i:1h\'>").1L({12:b+1},1U).30({12:b+1},K),g=a[1].1t,n=a[1].1a,3Q=2);31.17(M);31.17(h);a.2q({13:M,1t:l,1a:p,16:0,18:0,1u:!1,35:0});a.2q({13:h,1t:g,1a:n,16:0,18:0,1u:!1,35:0})}r(a.i-1)}1F 1==b?(2e.2y(),2o.2y()):2==b&&2e.2y();1<b&&r(1);r(0);c(3N)}}$(u).4s("3f",2G);11(2H.3O)1X=Q.1C({5a:0,59:!0,4e:!1,57:4}),1X.15("7m",J),1X.15("7l",3l),1X.15("4U",39);1F{11(k.5h)G.15("3b",d);k.3y&&(G.15("47",m),1X=Q.1C({3V:!1,4e:!1,4u:!1}),1X.15("4U",39))}})();2G();!1I(k.1O)&&0<k.1O&&7.1f(1c,k.1O,{3Z:2G,3T:-1});1c.12=x;1c.4t=e;1c.4y=6(c){11(1==w&&0==2g&&2a&&0==S&&(0<=p-1||k.1s)){9 b=p;0<b?b--:b=a.i-1;x(b,1m 0!==c?c:!1)}};1c.4A=6(){f(w+k.3o)};1c.4g=6(){f(w-k.3o)};1c.5A=R;1c.7F=Y;1c.3g=c;1c.1a=6(){1g a[p].1a};1c.3U=f;1c.5T=a.i;1c.1s=k.1s;1c.3d=k.3d;1c.36=k.36;1c.5P=$.3e({},k);1c.3f=2G}})(3K);(6(u){u.6c=6(n,a,g){6 h(a){a.37?a.37():a.50=!1}6 l(a,c){11("7I"===$.3z(a)){A=a;c=1m 0===c||1I(c)?b.1y:c;9 d=A?4f:2I,e=2Z 3Y;39&&A&&e.1M(7.1f(2N,0,{1v:"24",3S:"40"}));e.1M(7.1f(x,c,d));39&&!A&&e.1M(7.1f(2N,0,{1v:"1E",3S:"40",3P:!1}));A&&!1U&&e.1M(q);A&&1V()}1g A}6 q(){9 c=a.i;1U=!0;19(9 b=0;b<c;b++)a[b].3w||(a[b].1u&&29(b),a[b].3w||(1U=!1))}6 2k(a){r=x.16();L=x.18();f<r?N=!1:(N=!0,J=a.1Y.2h[0].2n,3l=m,Z=H,H=J,V())}6 C(a){N&&(Z=H,H=a.1Y.2h[0].2n,m=3l+H-J,a={2f:28,3P:!1,1r:b.1r},s?a.x=m:a.1Q=m,7.1f(T,0,a))}6 I(a){N&&(E=0>Z-H?1:-1,P=3a.3X(Z-H),3k.5z.7K("5s",O));N=!1}6 O(){0<P?(m+=P*E,f<r?P=0:m>b.3j?(P=0,m=b.3j):m+f-r<-b.3j&&(P=0,m=-b.3j-f+r),1V(0,!1,!1),P-=b.67):(1V(b.1y),V())}6 V(a){P=0;3k.5z.7E("5s",O)}6 2j(c){21=0.5*(b.2T-K.16())+"1k";2G=0.5*(b.3v-K.18())+"1k";K.3M();c=b.2C;19(9 d=a.i,e=0;e<d;e++)14!=a[e].2b&&a[e].2b.1J("20",c)}6 2i(c){c=c.j.12;a[c].1u||(7.o(a[c].2b,{1i:"1h",1A:21,1T:2G}),7.1f(a[c].2b,b.1y,{1G:1}))}6 2d(c){c=c.j.12;a[c].1u=!0;1m 0!==a[c].2b&&14!==a[c].2b&&(a[c].2b.3M(),a[c].2b=14);29(c);a[c].1j.17(a[c].13);a[c].1j.1C({5a:0,59:!0,4e:!1,57:1}).15("22",{12:c},W)}6 29(d){11(!a[d].3w){9 f=a[d].13.16(),h=a[d].13.18();11(0!=f&&0!=h){9 l=f*(e/h),m=h*(c/f),g=0,n=0;"7D"==b.4F?m<=e?l=c:m=e:"5j"==b.4F?m>=e?l=c:m=e:(l=f,m=h);g=0.5*(c-l);n=0.5*(e-m);f=2Z 3Y;f.1M(7.1f(a[d].13,0,{16:l+"1k",18:m+"1k",x:g,y:n,1i:"1h"}));f.1M(7.1f(a[d].13,b.1y,{1G:1,1v:"24",1r:b.1r}));a[d].3w=!0}}}6 W(a){1Z(a.j.12)}6 X(a){r=x.16();L=x.18();11(R!=r||Y!=L)1V(),R=r,Y=L}6 1V(d,e,h){r=x.16();L=x.18();d=d||0;e=1m 0!==e?e:!0;9 l={2f:28,16:f,1r:b.1r},g=23*(b.2T+b.3t),n=!1,q={3P:!1},u=!1;e&&(f<r?(m=0.5*(r-f),n=!0):0<m?m=0:0>m+f-r?m=-(f-r):2E&&(u=!0));1m 0!==h&&h&&(0>m+g?m=-g:m+g+c>r?m=r-(g+c):2E&&(u=!0));s?(l.x=m,q.x=m-1):(l.1Q=m,q.1Q=m-1);!1U&&e&&(h=e=0,n?h=a.i-1:(e=3a.3X(3a.5k(m/c)),h=e+3a.5k(r/c)),h>a.i-1&&(h=a.i-1),l.48=2A,l.4D=[e,h]);n=2Z 3Y;2E&&u&&n.1M(7.1f(T,0,q));n.1M(7.1f(T,d,l))}6 2A(c,b){19(9 d=c;d<=b;d++)a[d].1u||a[d].13.1J("20",a[d].1t)}6 1Z(c){1I(c)||(0>c?c=0:c>a.i-1&&(c=a.i-1),B!=c&&(23=c,7.o(a[B].1j,{33:b.2x+"1k 3A "+b.4P}),7.o(a[23].1j,{33:b.2x+"1k 3A "+b.4K}),T.17(a[23].1j),B=23,$.3n(b.2w)&&b.2w.3m(14,b.2X)),1V(b.1y,!0,!0));1g 23}3k.4I="4Z";9 b=$.3e({2T:75,3v:75,1y:0.5,1r:5p.5n,2C:14,4F:"5j",2x:2,4K:"#7v",4P:"66",3t:0,67:1,3j:1w,2B:!1,1O:-1,4W:{1G:1},55:{1G:0},2s:!0,2w:14,2X:14},g),x=$(n),r=x.16(),L=x.18(),R=0,Y=0,c=b.2T+2*b.2x,e=b.3v+2*b.2x,f=(b.2T+b.3t)*a.i-b.3t+2*b.2x,T=$("<1j 1p=\'16:"+(f-1)+"1k; 18:"+(b.3v+2*b.2x)+"1k; 1A:41; 1T:41; 1i:1h;\'></1j>"),d=$("<1j 1p=\'16:1K; 18:1K; 1A:-1K; 1T:-1K; 1i:1h; 4b:1E\'></1j>"),s=2H.63,23=0,B=0,m=0,J=0,3l=0,P=m=0,E=1,Z=0,H=0,N=!1,A=b.2B,4f=b.4W,2I=b.55,1U=!1,K="3x"===$.3z(b.2C)?$("<1B>").1L(2j):14,21=0,2G=0;g=5U.5S.2V();n=-1<g.3B("6M");g=-1<g.3B("6H");9 2E=n&&g,2N=x.2D(),39=b.2s&&"6F"==2N.j("1q");14!=K&&(7.o(K,
```

Comment: можно выполнить его :-)

Comment: Никак - он не полный. Чтоб его деобфусцировать, нужен как минимум скрипт целиком

Comment: Я бы не стал, вдруг вирусняк. Робот ПС зайдет и метку поставит.

Comment: вообще первое, что надо сделать, когда сталкиваетесь с подобно выглядищим js - это `ctrl+ f` `eval`.

Comment: Скрипт полный, просто не влез в сообщение по максимальным символам

Comment: @Darth, eval не обязателен, он может просто собираться так что упоминание _eval_ скорее всего не будет :)

Comment: @Darth, https://0.s3.envato.com/files/79875644/js/TouchNSwipe.min.js вот полный скрипт

Comment: А вариант нагуглить [неминифицированный скрипт и документацию](https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin) по имени файла не рассматривается?

Comment: @Qwertiy, а я вообще думал он платный :-)

Comment: @grundy смотрите, вот eval 
    `tpx = function(a) {
        return a.charAt(3)
    },
    de3 = function(a) {
        return a.charAt(3) + a.charAt(1) + a.charAt(4)
    },
    
 fy = window[tpx("ptfe") + de3("3axvlfd")];`

Comment: Дальше заменяете этот eval на console .log и скрипт у вас в руках

Comment: @Darth, :-D я к тому что поиском строки _eval_ тут не обойдешься

Comment: Универсальный способ включает пункт номер раз: разобраться как оно работает. Потом все просто.